# How to use TikaCLI Features in Java Source Code?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, apache-tika, xslf

I'm trying to extract embedded Files from office documents using Apache Tika. Using the Tika CLI (cmd), everything works perfectly well. But I have to integrate it in my Java Source Code in Eclipse.

So what I did is:

```
public static void saveEmbedds(String inputfile, String outputfile) throws Exception{
    try{
        String[] arguments = new String[]{"-z", "--extract-dir=" + removeExtension(outputfile), inputfile};
        System.out.println("Using TIKA CLI to dedect embedded Files. Target Directory: "+ removeExtension(outputfile));
        TikaCLI.main(arguments);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("Exception in saveEmbedds, during search in File: " + inputfile + "\r\nDetails: " + e);
    }

}
```

This actually works for every filetype, expect `.pptx`. When inputfile is a .pptx File, it produces a lot of Errors. Using cmd the same thing works.

```
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextShape.getTextType()Lorg/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/Placeholder; 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XSLFPowerPointExtractorDecorator.extractContent(XSLFPowerPointExtractorDecorator.java:154) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XSLFPowerPointExtractorDecorator.buildXHTML(XSLFPowerPointExtractorDecorator.java:88) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.AbstractOOXMLExtractor.getXHTML(AbstractOOXMLExtractor.java:110) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(OOXMLExtractorFactory.java:112) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:87) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI$OutputType.process(TikaCLI.java:190) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:491) 
12.04.2016 15:31:33 945     at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:144)
```

**Is there any better way to use the features of Apache Tika CLI?** I also tried the example code of [ExtractEmbeddedFiles](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ExtractEmbeddedFiles.java) but I didn't work for embedded `.ppt` Files.

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of Apache POI on your classpath - see [this Apache POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)

Comment: @Gagravarr I tried to use to use the [testcode](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) but it throws the following error: `Failed to import org.apache.poi.hslf.HSLFSlideShow`. Is this HSLFSlideShow even included in POI-3.14? I'm actually using the following jars: 
`ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar, poi-3.14-20160307.jar, poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar, poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar, xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar,  tika-app.1.12.jar.` 

I checked twice, if any jar is from an older version and added the newest ones, but still same error.

Comment: Try refreshing the FAQ page - it's `org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShow` now

Comment: @Gagravarr Thank you for updating the page. :) At line `URL res = classloader.getResource` eclipse gives me an error that URL cannot be found in any class. What do I have to import to use this?

Comment: It's `java.net.URL` - the normal one!

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for your input! What I get now as output is the following: `POI Core came from file:/X:/OfficeExtraction.jar!/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class`  
`POI OOXML came from file:/X:/OfficeExtraction.jar!/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.class` 
`POI Scratchpad came from file:/X:/OfficeExtraction.jar!/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.class` 
How can I now guess what is wrong with my files (wrong version)?

Comment: What on earth is `OfficeExtraction.jar`, where did it come from, and why have you put it on your java classpath?

Comment: @Gagravarr Oh sorry, you cannot know... OfficeExtraction.jar is a runnable jar file, which contains all mentioned POI Classes (imported as jar) and my own code. I have to export my project as jar file, otherwise i cannot run the file. So if I run it in eclipse, output is: `.../poi-3.14/poi-3.14 20160307.jar!/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class, .../poi-3.14/poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar!/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.class, .../poi-3.14/poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar!/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.class` 
It seems to be alright...